# Clarification on a basic stat problem

Tags: probability, statistics

I need a clarification on this homework problem I'm getting done. The question is as follows:

> For each positive integer $n$, let $P_n = \Big (\frac 12 \Big)^n.$ Consider the events $A = \{n:1 \leq b \leq 10\}$, ...

and it goes on. Now one of the questions would be what is $P(A)$. 
I'm not sure if $P(A) = P(\{10\})$  or $P(A) = P(\{1,2,3,\ldots,9,10\})$, which I wouldn't even know how to use the $P(\{n\})$ formula then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is a little unusual. But if the sample space consists of $1,2,3,\dots$ then
$$\Pr(A)=\Pr(1)+\Pr(2)+\cdots +\Pr(10).$$
The addition is straightforward to do by hand. It turns out that the sum is equal to $1-\frac{1}{2^{10}}$. This can also be done by using the usual formula for the sum of a finite geometric series.

Comment: It didn't happen. Delete your two comments.

Comment: The limit of $A=\{n: 1\ge n \ge \infty\}$ is $1.$ :)